# How can I improve Mac OS X's Location Services?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, geolocation

I recently moved to a new apartment in a new building in a new neighborhood in San Francisco (central waterfront / Mission Bay). I know that Apple uses Wi-Fi for determining location, but Mac OS X Mountain Lion is unable to determine my location given only four Wi-Fi networks around me. What can I do to register my geo-coordinates so that my Mac knows where it is?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if Apple is still using Skyhook for their location services, but they have a page where you can submit the lat/long and MAC address of an access point:

http://www.skyhookwireless.com/howitworks/submit_ap.php

Comment: Maybe not: seems like the bootstrapped with skyhook, [then decided to use their own](http://techcrunch.com/2010/07/29/apple-location/)

Answer (score 0):

Less practical; have you and your friends with iphones hang around your house with Wifi enabled. With WiFi on, iOS tags Wireless MACs they see with GPS locations, and on sync will send this to apple to use in mapping.

I don't think you actually need to log in to a Wifi network for this to work, iOS just sees what MACs are visible over the air. (Corrections are welcome)